# AngularJS + Onsen-Ui + Phonegap slow click behavior

Tags: angularjs, performance, scope, click, onsen-ui

today i was dealing with an issue when clicking a button using ng-click directive in angular, in the desktop obviously didn't see any time delay, but when running the Phonegap application in the iPad then the problem comes out, let me show you the code that was causing this slow behaviour, i have two examples that have the same symptom:

Example 1

```
$scope.addProductFn = function(index){
        var product = $scope.products[index];
        $scope.order.unshift(product);

        /* the code below make the click slow */
        $scope.orderTotal = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.order, function(value, key) {
           $scope.orderTotal += value.price;
        });
};
```

Example 2

```
$scope.addProductFn = function(index){
        var product = $scope.products[index];
        $scope.order.unshift(product);

        /* the code below make the click slow */
        $scope.orderTotal += product.price;
};
```

If i remove those lines, click response work as expected, pretty fast

```
$scope.addProductFn = function(index){
        var product = $scope.products[index];
        $scope.order.unshift(product);
};
```

And here is how i show the total

```
<span class="header">Orden: {{ orderTotal | currency }}</span>
```

As you see there's no complicated code but when trying to calculate the scope var "$scope.orderTotal" then the clicks on the buttons are slow, the active state gets longer.

Any ideas about this?

At least i know what causing the slow thing, but i wonder why!

Thanks for your help

Comment: You might be on to something. I wonder if the slow down is occurring because of the $digest loop run when `$scope.orderTotal` is updated. Especially in example 1 where you have a loop. I have done similar things developing with Angular and PhoneGap but not using OnsenUI. My responsiveness was fine. Since OnsenUI is based off Angular directives, maybe a lot more is firing during the $digest loop than your update.

Answer (score 0):

slow behavior is typical for mobile devices as they have 300ms delay by default to detect doubletap. You can bypass this by using [fastclick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) library

Comment: The 300ms is not the problem i think, removing part of the code as in the example the tap is pretty fast, i think is something related with the $scope var im trying to calculate beacuse removing that code the tap is fast, no 300ms delay

Comment: I use fastClick for Angular app on android and I have to hold my finger for 2 seconds to actually trigger a click. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do you pushPage() to the page which has own controller? Firstly, Onsen UI pushPage initialize the controller of the target page, then execute the transit. So if you write the heavy logic in the target page, your transition will be delayed. If you want to delay initialization of the controller, use $timeout to delay.

```
app.controller('pushPageTargetPageCtrl', function($scope, $timeout){
    //Delay Controller initialization and do page transition firstly.
    $timeout(function(){
        //Do Stuff
        var sum = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < 999999; i++) {
            sum += i;
        }
    }, 500);
});
```

Comment: No no, its not problem with transitions, just imagine this scenario, everything is loaded, even the controllers, but in the view side i have some buttons that call a function thats defined in the controller, but i have to remark that everything is loaded, if you see my examples when the click function have that logic, buttons are unresponsive, if remove that part are fast, but if you see is simple code nothing special, but anyway that cause some delay in the click button